# Distribution of the Number of Distinct Items in a Sequence of Independent Random Variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Suppose I have a finite sequence of independent discrete random variables (which are NOT identically distributed), denoted by $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ such that each $X_i$ has a probability mass function $f_{X_i}(x_i)$.  What is the distribution of the random variable $Y$ corresponding to the number of distinct values in this sequence?

For example, if the sequence consists of $1, 2, 2, 3, 4$, then $Y=4$ since $2$ is only counted once.

Remember, the key here is that each $X_i$ can have ANY discrete distribution.  So, for example, maybe $X_1$ follows a uniform distribution, $X_2$ follows a binomial distribution, etc.  **How can we generically represent the distribution of $Y$ as  dependent on the $f_{X_i}(x_i)$ and the value of $n$?**  Is it possible?

Comment: Just to clear up some possible ambiguities... I assume that when you say "discrete distribution," I assume that you're referring to a distribution over the positive integers? Non-negative integers (i.e., integers $\geq 0$)? or all integers?

Comment: I wasn't intending to limit it to that; for example, a particular variant of the negative binomial distribution consists of all of the integers greater than or equal to its first parameter.  If $X$ follows $NB(r, p)$ then the support of $X$ is $r, r+1, r+2, ...$  Of course, I can understand how this lack of consistency of the support can complicate the problem significantly, but perhaps it is still possible to generalize this.